# How can write title chapter of thesis?

Tags: thesis

I write a thesis, and I want to help me 
how can be written the title of the chapter without the number appearing on the page (page without number)?
And how to write the proof of the theorem without the appearance of the number of proof?

Comment: `\chapter*{Title}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you want an unnumbered chapter, or the first page of a chapter to be  unumbered?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you should use `\chapter*{Title of your chapter}` for it to appear **without** the number. 
If you still want to add it to the table of contents, use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title of your chapter}.`

The same works for equation environments: `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}` disables auto-numbering.

---

**Edited**:

You can try using \thispagestyle{empty} to remove the style from the page where the title appears.

Also, consider using a package that has documentation, such as ClassicThesis, from André Miede. You can find more information about it and LaTeX formatting in the book *LaTeX Cookbook* from Stefan Kottwitz.

Comment: I want to  write the title of the chapter on page without number

Comment: I am using this formt

Comment: \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}{}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{}]%
    {\fancyplain{}{\normalsize\bfseries\rightmark}}
\chead[\fancyplain{}{}]%
      {\fancyplain{}{}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{}]%
     {\fancyplain{}{\normalsize\bfseries\thepage}}
\cfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]%
      {\fancyplain{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}

Comment: Have you tried using `\thispagestyle{empty}` to remove the style from the page where the title appears?

Also, consider using a package that has documentation, such as [ClassicThesis](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/ClassicThesis.pdf), from André Miede. You have find more information about it and LaTeX formatting in the book LaTeX Cookbook from Stefan Kottwitz.

Comment: @user290397, please convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: @Zarko, edited answer and expanded it with the info.